How to start Docker Compose in detached mode and keep streaming logs until all services are healthy?
My goal is simple - it is to create a script that sets up my local environment before tests are ran, and logs of my containers are vital to that - sometimes, due to some env changes, the startup fails and I need to see immediately what went wrong.
So I've been trying to figure out a way how to start Docker Compose in detached mode, but still keep the logs streaming until either all services are healthy, or until one fails.
My best guess for now was to just poll healthiness every couple of seconds and also fetching logs during that poll, but that is an awful solution.


My best guess for now was to just poll healthiness every couple of seconds and also fetching logs during that poll, but that is an awful solution.

I think that's probably the easiest solution; it's probably what I would put together if I needed to do the same thing. Something like:
docker compose up -d

docker compose logs -f &
logpid=$!

statusfile=$(mktemp statusXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $statusfile" EXIT

while :; do
    docker compose ps -q | xargs -n1 docker container inspect --format '{{ .State.Health.Status}}' >"$statusfile" 2>/dev/null
    if ! grep -vq healthy "$statusfile"; then
        break
    fi

    sleep 1
done

kill -9 $logpid

I though perhaps we could do something clever like having a container that waits until all the other containers are healthy and then writes something to a pipe, like the healthcheck container in the following example:
services:
  web1:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      apk add darkhttpd curl
      exec darkhttpd /var/www/localhost/htdocs --port 8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-Ssf", "http://localhost:8080"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 2s

  web2:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      apk add darkhttpd curl
      exec darkhttpd /var/www/localhost/htdocs --port 8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-Ssf", "http://localhost:8080"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 2s

  healthcheck:
    profiles:
    - healthcheck
    depends_on:
      web1:
        condition: service_healthy
      web2:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      echo OK > /pipes/healthcheck
    volumes:
      - ./pipes:/pipes

The idea being that one could wait for all containers to be healthy by doing something like:
grep -q OK pipes/healthcheck

Unfortunately, docker compose up doesn't return until all containers have been started, which means it blocks until the healthcheck container starts, so we never have the opportunity to stream the logs.

Unfortunately, seems like there's no sane way to do what I want - I've tried the approach you've suggested, but the log streaming, unfortunately, simply doesn't work the way I expect it to (being streamed to stdout) - it's being overwritten by Docker's own status messages regarding containers' startup. It's really weird there's no built-in option to show logs while containers are becoming healthy.
